# How do I bulk insert data into SQL Server without using bcp?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

I have SQL Server 2005 DB with a number of tables of the form

```
Table (id <Primary Key, Identity column>, name <VarChar (255)>)
```

I have a Java Servlet that needs to be able to bulk add information to those tables.  The SQL Server DB is running on a different machine than the Servlet, and I do not have access to the file system of that machine.

My understanding is that I can't use Bulk Insert because it requires the data file to be on the server's file system (which I can't do), it requires you to fill in all fields (can't do, one field is an identity field that is filled in by the DB) or to have the unfilled field be the last one (I put the identity / id field first, and have no desire to change that), and requires the format file to be on the Server's file system.

In MySQL, I'd simply use Load Data Local InFile.  SQL Server 2005 appears to lack such a capability.  Am I just missing something?  Is there any way for me to add more than one record at a time to a SQL Server table w/o using bcp or Bulk Insert?

TIA,

Greg

Comment: [data file - "Is the full path of the data file that contains data to import into the specified table or view. BULK INSERT can import data from a disk (including network, floppy disk, hard disk, and so on)."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO Table (column_name, ...)
Values
(column_values,...),(column_values,...),(column_values, ...), ...
```

Note this is possible with SQL Server 2008

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx

For SQL Server 2005 and Under you would need to do something like this

```
INSERT INTO table (column_name, column_name, ...)
SELECT column_value , column_value, ...
UNION ALL
SELECT column_value , column_value, ...
UNION ALL
SELECT column_value , column_value, ...
UNION ALL
SELECT column_value , column_value, ...
UNION ALL
SELECT column_value , column_value, ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that works.  I'm going to be sending this to SQL Server via JDBC.  Do you know that maximum length of a command you can send to SQL Server 2005 using JDBC 4?

Comment: No I dont.. but considering your need you could just batch out by say every 50 or 100 lines in your text file.  So every 50-100 lines in your text file run the insert statement.  I would try to see how much the JDBC command would hold first

Answer (score 1):

So you have neither access to the filesystem on the servlet machine nor the SQL Server?  (I'm not sure how you would do this in MySQL either, since LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE needs a file).

ADO.NET supports a SqlBulkCopy API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: Nope, I have access to the servlet's file system, I just don't have access to the SQL Server server's file system.  And my Servlet is running on Linux, not Windows.

Comment: @Greg Dougherty You could try `BULK INSERT FROM` on the SQL Server pointing to a network share service account would need permissions, share would need to exist, etc.  Alternatively, insert via an SP using a big XML?